# Servlet mapping with annotation does not get resolved by Google App Engine Dev Server

Tags: google-app-engine

Instead of servlet mapping in the web.xml, i'm trying to use annotation to map the servlet to urls as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "GuestbookServlet", urlPatterns = "/guestbook")
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

And I have also declared the 3.0 spec for servlet in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="false">

</web-app>
```

However, when I run it on my local environment the response returned is 404.

It works however if I just map the servlets in the web.xml. What am I doing wrong? Does GAE still not support 3.0 specs?

Answer (score 5):

Servlet 3.0 spec is not supported by GAE/J

It's still on the roadmap: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/features#roadmap_features

You can star this issue to help show your support for this feature: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091

This ticket has been opened a lonnnggg time though.

Comment: Its worth noting this was recently commented on by one of the GAE Product Managers - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091#hc77

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following JSP code,

```
Server info == <%=application.getServerInfo()%><br/>
Major==<%=application.getMajorVersion()%><br/>
Minor==<%=application.getMinorVersion()%><br/>
JSP version is <%= JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion()%><br/>
```

I see

Server info == Google App Engine/Google App Engine/1.8.1
 Major==2
 Minor==5
 JSP version is 2.1

You could run it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet 3.1 are now supported on AppEngine.

> ... In addition to support for an updated JDK and Jetty 9 with Servlet 3.1 specs...

Announcement: 
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html

[Here is a code example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/java8/HelloAppEngine.java#L31)